# $x_n\le y_n\le x_{n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Could any one tell me which of this is correct statement?I did not get any hint.

I get $x_1\le y_1\le x_3$

$x_2\le y_2\le x_4$ etc but how to know all these $4$ properties?

Comment: Have you tried coming up with counterexample sequences for any of the statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try to make sequences where some of properties 1,2,3,4 do not hold.

**Hint**: Try something like $x_n = y_n = n+(-1)^n$.

Once you see several properties fail to hold, you can focus on proving the remaining one.

Also, the squeeze theorem might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot easily express $x_{i+1}$ in terms of $x_i$ you can say something about their max or min. For example, let $a=min(x_1,x_2)$. What can you say about all subsequent $x_n$ relative to $a$? What can you say about the sequence $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ relative to $a$?